# Two insert query... in the same click

Tags: php, mysql

I have two text fields and a button, on the click i need to save them into MySQL Tables.

The top text box field data in table 1 and data in text box in table two...

How to perform it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, i guess your form execute some server-side PHP.
Then in this PHP juste use mysql_query() 2 times, with your 2 insert.

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL does not seem to support multiple inserts in otwo tables you can do it with a transaction with two inserts or with a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-syntax.html).